# Safari relative position inside flex

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've been testing on Safari 602.1 on iOS 10 as I don't have other device. I use Bootstrap 4.1 and I'm having problem relatively positioning element inside a column. I tried auto prefixing Bootstrap and it didn't help.

The text is not positioned at all.

Screen from iPhone:

[image: Screen from iPhone]

It works everywhere except Safari, I'm desperate.

http://jsbin.com/tigowet/edit?html,css,output

```css
.box {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 50%;
}

.box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.box a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.box a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.box input {
    width: 100%;
}

.bgDarkBlue {
    background-color: #3F51B5;
}

.shadowBox {
    box-shadow: 7px 5px 25px black;
}

.verticalHorizontal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box shadowBox bgDarkBlue">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
     <img src="http://tusla.info/images/safari-column/evaluation.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 pl-sm-0">
     <h1 class="position-relative verticalHorizontal">Text</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>

<div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an ios device to test on but I would move relative position up one level and make the `.verticalHorizontal` absolute:

```css
.box {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.box a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box input {
  width: 100%;
}

.bgDarkBlue {
  background-color: #3F51B5;
}

.shadowBox {
  box-shadow: 7px 5px 25px black;
}

.verticalHorizontal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box shadowBox bgDarkBlue">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
     <img src="http://tusla.info/images/safari-column/evaluation.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 pl-sm-0 position-relative">
     <h1 class="verticalHorizontal">Text</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>

<div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it behaves differently but basically I think that Safari on iOS somehow miscomputed boundaries for -50%&-50% element's positioning. So the -50% was computed from different point of origin. When we specified the parent container's position as `relative`, we actually specified boundaries for content inside that is then positioned relatively to the parent.